# Can <noscript> have multiple assets listed?

Tags: html, assets, noscript

Can the `<noscript>` tag contain more than one asset? Example:

```
<noscript>
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css"&gt;
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"&gt;
</noscript>
```

Or does each asset need to be in its own `<noscript>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN tells us:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

> When scripting is disabled and when it is a descendant of the `<head>` element: in any order, zero or more `<link>` elements, zero or more `<style>` elements, and zero or more `<meta>` elements.
>
> When scripting is disabled and when it isn't a descendant of the `<head>` element: any transparent content, but no `<noscript>` element must be among its descendants.
>   Otherwise: flow content or phrasing content.

In your case, multiple `link` elements will be fine.